# Show Single URL for navigation in Ionic 4 PWA

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

Need to show only single url for `navigating` through all the pages

**For example :** 
    http://localhost:8100/ `(login page)`
    http://localhost:8100/ `(home page)`
    http://localhost:8100/ `(about-us page)`

instead of 
    http://localhost:8100/home,,,
    http://localhost:8100/login,,,
    http://localhost:8100/about-us,,,

Need help to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use named outlets. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48244449/multiple-components-per-route-in-angular

Comment: You can use skipLocationChange as described here https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this in your component

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.location.replaceState("/");
}
```

or you can do following

```
this.router.navigate(['/about-us'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```